# Is using hardware performance counters a good idea

Tags: c, linux, performancecounter

Say I want to implement a software that uses hardware performance counters such as those for counting retired stores. Note that alternative solutions without the performance counters are possible but might be relatively a little inefficient. However, I can sacrifice performance a bit for portability and power efficiency. Also, note that the performance counters will be kept on the whole time.

How good hardware performance counters are in consuming power. Secondly, Are there popular platforms or processors, single or multicore, which don't have performance counters. If so, could you kindly name them.

Comment: You typically do not turn hardware performance counters on. They are there and you choose to read them (or not). Reading them costs the same as reading a special-purpose register (a couple of cycles at most). The i486 and previous IA32 processors did not have much in terms of performance counters; I don't know if that counts as "popular".

Comment: Are you interested in x86? in ARM? in MIPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PAPI is a common profiler program that allows you to compile into the code and access the hardwrae counters. From my own experience, it doesn't have a noticable effect on performance.

Although I don't know for sure, I would assume that it will not increase power consumption because hardware counters are always enabled in the hardware. It's just a matter of reading them.

As far as I know, I'm not aware of any modern non-embedded processors that don't have performance counters. I may wrong. Someone care to correct me?

Comment: What about embedded ones? Any idea?

Comment: I know very little about embedded processors. But given the very nature of them (small, low-power), they aren't always for performance and hence don't always have performance counters.

Answer (score 1):

It's a some time ago since I used performance counter but maybe [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/) can help you with some stuff.